# Single entry Schengen national visa

Tags: visas, schengen

I am from Georgia and have a D category long-term Schengen visa but is marked 01 which means that it's a single entry. Am I able to go from Poland to France by plane?

Comment: @DavidRicherby: When I left the comment, the question just said "D category long-term visa" without any indication that it was a Schengen visa.  I guess Dorothy managed to deduce that but I could not.

Comment: Note that this question is no longer unclear: the asker has given the details of what visa they have (which were missing from the original question).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You will only be *entering* Schengen once. When you enter Poland, you are entering the Schengen Area; when you then fly to France, you are moving within the Schengen Area.

Comment: Thanks David a lot:) you are sure about it yes? Because someone told me that I am not allowed to leave Poland, Should I have documents or something with me?

Comment: @Janny You should have your residence permit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter from the country that you obtained your visa first. After that you are free to go anywhere you want. You can fly back to your country from any schengen country as well.

Comment: Your first sentence is incorrect. You're supposed to get a Schengen visa from the country where you're spending the most time, not the country that you'll be entering first.